# Internet sharing from MacBook / Studio lingers after switched off

Tags: macos, iphone, network, wifi, internet-sharing

I guess for a bit of context: I'm trying to deploy a WebDriverAgent on iOS 17 which requires a live Internet connection for the 1st time deployment as per: [Provisioning profile updates - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-profiles/provisioning-profile-updates/)

Now to the issue at hand:

Setup -> The iPhone is connected to a MacStudio. In order to get a live Internet connection, I have enabled Internet Sharing from the MacStudio Ethernet port to iPhone USB. All working perfectly fine, able to deploy the agent and take full remote control of the phone. With this out of the way, the sharing is switched off on the MacStudio.

The issue -> With the phone still connected to the MacStudio via the USB-C cable and the internet sharing off, I'm now trying to connect the phone to Wi-Fi. It connects but I get the warning message to say that there is no Internet connection.

My theory -> The MacStudio continues to broadcast / give an IP to the phone even tho I have disabled the network sharing which is then causing a conflict when connecting the Wi-Fi.

If I unplug the phone from the Mac the Wi-Fi will start working as normal, but doing so I lose the authorisation for the WebDriverAgent and I'm back to square 1.

Any way I can fully switch the sharing off? Any processes I can kill, anything like that?

I tried:

- disabled the thunderbridge associated with InternetSharing
- various IP configurations
- unloaded the NetworkSharing.plist
- configured the NAT to use a certain IP range only
- upgraded to latest iOS